# Reading binary file using java.io.DataInputStream results in wrong value

Tags: java, c

I have a difficulty on reading a file contains stock price which is in binary format. I have been trying to browse for an answer in here and googling for any tutorial of using DataInputStream, yet still no luck. None of them are working.

I have also read about big and small endian conversion in Java but it still gives me the wrong value. Is there anyone has any experience on reading *.mkt file using Java? I got the code which is working fine but it is written in C but the requirement is to rewrite it in Java.

The purpose of the method to get several fields out of each block of binary data as specified by

`if (j == 1 || j == 4 || j == 9 || j == 11 || j == 12 || j == 13 || j == 14)`

Below is the spec for the binary data and the code i wrote for testing.

> ￼**HEADER**
>
> > Transcode  -> Short 2 Bytes 
> >  
> >     Timestamp  -> Long 4Bytes 
> >  
> >     Message    -> Short 2 Bytes
>
> **DATA**
>
> > Security Token -> Short 2 Bytes 
> >     Last Traded Price -> Long 4 Bytes 
> >     Best Buy Quantity -> Long 4 Bytes 
> >  
> >     Best Buy Price -> Long 4 Bytes 
> >     Best Sell Quantity -> Long 4 Bytes 
> >     Best Sell Price -> Long 4 Bytes 
> >     Total Traded Quantity -> Long 4 Bytes 
> >  
> >     Average Traded Price -> Long 4 Bytes 
> >  
> >     Open Price -> Long 4 Bytes 
> >     High Price -> Long 4 Bytes 
> >     Low Price -> Long 4 Bytes 
> >     ClosePrice -> Long 4 Bytes 
> >     Filler -> Long 4 Bytes (Blank)
>
> **Total 50 Bytes**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File("<Path to the file>.mkt"));
    List<String> results = readPriceFromStream(inputStream);
    inputStream.close();
    System.out.println(results.get(0));
}

public static List<String> readPriceFromStream(InputStream sourceInputStream) throws Exception {
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();

    DataInputStream inputStream = new DataInputStream(sourceInputStream);

    int[] byteSequences = new int[]{2, 4, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4};
    int len = 50;

    for (int i = 1; i <= inputStream.available(); i += len) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        int read = 0;

        for (int j = 0; j < byteSequences.length; j++) {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[byteSequences[j]];

            if (j == 1 || j == 4 || j == 9 || j == 11 || j == 12 || j == 13 || j == 14) {
                try {
                    sb.append(Integer.valueOf(inputStream.readLong())).append(",");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    sb.append("0").append(",");
                }
            } else {
                read = inputStream.read(buffer, 0, byteSequences[j]);
            }
        }

        if (read <= -1) {
            break;
        } else {
            String price = sb.toString();

            if (price.length() > 0) {
                price = price.substring(0, price.lastIndexOf(","));
                result.add(price);
            }
        }
    }

    if (result.size() > 0) {
        result.remove(0);
    }

    inputStream.close();
    return result;
}
```

** And following is the code snippet written in C **

```
for(i = 0; i <= fileLen; i=i+58) {
    fread(&TransCode, sizeof(signed short int), 1, input_filename);
    fread(&TimeStamp, sizeof(signed long int), 1, input_filename);

... Truncated for clarity ...
```

**Sample Data**
Transcode,Timestamp,  MessageLength, SecurityToken, LastTradedPrice, BestBuyQuantity, BestBuyPrice, BestSellQuantity, BestSellPrice, TotalTradedQuantity, AverageTradedPrice, OpenPrice, HighPrice, LowPrice,   ClosePrice, Blank

> 5,1435905898,58,7,34600,1,34585,29,34600,47479,34777,34560,35100,34500,34670,0

**Result from the `main(String[] args)`**

> -2416744146710362880,-615304298158882816,-7614115823107390437,149649579050240,22110525258626,139753974434839,144387995842138645

If this is duplicating another question or has been answered before, please kindly help to point me to that question/answer cause I am desperate now (been spending half day tried to make it work) and i have limited knowledge on this kind of binary thing. Thanks.

Comment: Java's `long` is 8 bytes, not 4 bytes.

Comment: Tried to change to read with `readInt` and `readShort` but still got the wrong value

Comment: Jeez, your code is horrible. Hold on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
Path path = Paths.get("path/to/file");
byte[] byteArray= Files.readAllBytes(path);
ByteBuffer bbuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(byteArray);
short numS = bbuffer.getShort();
System.out.println("short: " + numS);
```

If the Endian is wrong (e.g. 1280 instead of 5) try `Short.reverseBytes(numS);` for a single value or `bbuffer.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);` for all elements.

`java.nio.ByteBuffer` also supports reading specific positions, e.g. `java.nio.ByteBuffer.getShort(int)` and of course different data types.
Just read the file line by line (or in 50 byte chunks) with the `ByteBuffer`.

Comment: I tried your suggestion and got the same result with `readShort` from DataInputStream. The output of printout above is ***1280*** whereas it should be ***5*** as i described in the sample data.

Comment: Can you post the hex-value of that file (with a hex-editor like ultra-edit)? In Java, the Short '5' is this in binary: `0000000000000101` or this in hex: `0005`, the Short 58 is `0000000000111010` in binary or `003A` in hex

Comment: It its an endian-Problem try `Short.reverseBytes(numS);`

Comment: Just use `bbuffer.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);`.

Comment: @hinneLinks Here are the first few lines hex values from the file (I've tried to sort the byte using LITTLE_ENDIAN and `reverseBytes` method and is still working).

05 00 6A 2F 96 55 3A 00 07 00 28 87 00 00 01 00 00 00 19 87 00 00 1D 00 00 00 28 87 00 00 77 B9 00 00 D9 87 00 00 00 87 00 00 1C 89 00 00 C4 86 00 00 6E 87 00 00 00 00 00 00 05 00 6A 2F 96 55 3A 00 0A 00 D9 76 00 00 C9 00 00 00 C5 76 00 00 0C 00 00 00 DE 76 00 00 C6 53 05 00 3E 77 00 00 F7 76 00 00 37 78 00 00 66 76 00 00 61 76 00 00 00 00 00 00 05 00 62 2F 96 55 3A 00 0D 00 C4 1B

Comment: Got it working with below sample code:
`
DataInputStream inputStream = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(new File("/Users/user/Documents/196.mkt")));
        byte[] buffered = ByteStreams.toByteArray(inputStream);
        ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(buffered).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
        try {
            while (true) {
                System.out.print(byteBuffer.getShort() + ",");
                System.out.print(byteBuffer.getInt() + ",");
                System.out.print(byteBuffer.getShort() + ",")
         ... [Truncated] ...
`

Answer (score 1):

Lose all that `for (int i = 1; i <= inputStream.available(); i += len) {` stuff. You're doing everything wrong.

After `DataInputStream inputStream = new DataInputStream(sourceInputStream);` create a loop that goes something like this...

```
try {
    while(true) {  // An EOFException is thrown when there's no more data
       short transcode = inputStream.readShort();
       int timestamp = inputStream.readInt();
       short message = inputStream.readShort();
       // and so on
    }
} catch(EOFException e) {
    // File processed
}
```

Don't forget the signedness of Java vs. the unsignedness of at least some of the data fields.

Edit: Since your data is actually in Little Endian form, it's better to use a `ByteBuffer` like hinneLinks advised:

```
Path path = Paths.get("path/to/file");
byte[] byteArray= Files.readAllBytes(path);
ByteBuffer bbuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(byteArray);
bbuffer.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN); // Set the byte order
short numS = bbuffer.getShort();
System.out.println("short: " + numS);
```

Comment: Your data has the "wrong" endianness (little endian 5 is big endian 1280). Guava has a LittleEndianDataInputStream.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the values in `byteSequences` you're using `readLong` to read values that are 32 bits numbers (4 bytes), but long in java is actually 64 bit value (8 bytes), so you end up reading two values.

Comment: as the specification says e.g. for Timestamp, its value type is Long 4 bytes. So do you have any trick or suggestion how to consume that using one of methods provided by DataInputStream?